# Regaining revoked access to YouTube account

Tags: java, youtube-api, access-token, youtube-data-api

I created an application to upload certain custom thumbnails to YouTube videos and it works fine but, I revoked access to my application from my YouTube account to test some things and my application no longer asks for access. Now whenever I attempt to use my application it only responds with:

```
 IOException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "error" : "invalid_grant",
   "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
 }
 com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "error" : "invalid_grant",
   "error_description" : "Token has been expired or revoked."
 }
```

I used the thumbnails set example from the YouTube page : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

I was wondering what I could change in my following code to get the login page to show up again so I can give access to my application again, my code is here:

```
private void uploadThumbnail(String videoId, BufferedImage thumbnail){
    YouTube youtube;
    String IMAGE_FILE_FORMAT = "image/png";
    // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
    // authenticated user's account.
    ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
    scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

    try {
        // Authorize the request.
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadthumbnail");

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                "youtube-cmdline-uploadthumbnail-sample").build();

        get.saveImg(thumbnail,"./Screens/screenshot0t.png");
        File imageFile = new File("./Screens/screenshot0t.png");

        // Create an object that contains the thumbnail image file's
        // contents.
        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(
                IMAGE_FILE_FORMAT, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile)));
        mediaContent.setLength(imageFile.length());

        // Create an API request that specifies that the mediaContent
        // object is the thumbnail of the specified video.
        Set thumbnailSet = youtube.thumbnails().set(videoId, mediaContent);

        // Set the upload type and add an event listener.
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = thumbnailSet.getMediaHttpUploader();

        // Indicate whether direct media upload is enabled. A value of
        // "True" indicates that direct media upload is enabled and that
        // the entire media content will be uploaded in a single request.
        // A value of "False," which is the default, indicates that the
        // request will use the resumable media upload protocol, which
        // supports the ability to resume an upload operation after a
        // network interruption or other transmission failure, saving
        // time and bandwidth in the event of network failures.
        uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);

        // Set the upload state for the thumbnail image.
        MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener progressListener = new MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader uploader) throws IOException {
                switch (uploader.getUploadState()) {
                    // This value is set before the initiation request is
                    // sent.
                    case INITIATION_STARTED:
                        System.out.println("Initiation Started");
                        break;
                    // This value is set after the initiation request
                    //  completes.
                    case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                        System.out.println("Initiation Completed");
                        break;
                    // This value is set after a media file chunk is
                    // uploaded.
                    case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                        System.out.println("Upload in progress");
                        System.out.println("Upload percentage: " + uploader.getProgress());
                        break;
                    // This value is set after the entire media file has
                    //  been successfully uploaded.
                    case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                        System.out.println("Upload Completed!");
                        break;
                    // This value indicates that the upload process has
                    //  not started yet.
                    case NOT_STARTED:
                        System.out.println("Upload Not Started!");
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        uploader.setProgressListener(progressListener);

        // Upload the image and set it as the specified video's thumbnail.
        ThumbnailSetResponse setResponse = thumbnailSet.execute();

        // Print the URL for the updated video's thumbnail image.
        System.out.println("\n================== Uploaded Thumbnail ==================\n");
        System.out.println("  - Url: " + setResponse.getItems().get(0).getDefault().getUrl());
        get.deleteFile(imageFile.getPath());
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Get another token! You've killed that one.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Sorry, I'm new to using oauth

Comment: You revoked access you will need to request access again.   Remember when i popped up asking you to grant permissions to access the account?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm wondering, what function could I use to make that screen appear again? Is it something like credential.getClientAuthentication()?

Comment: I think you have to go all the way back to `credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadthumbnail");` - it's the call to `authorize` that creates the credential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue with Gmail API, everything went back to normal after removing the stored credentials.

e.g. `rm  ~/.credentials/gmail-java-quickstart/StoredCredential`